# Grails read data from file and store it in an object

Tags: file, grails, load

I am trying to read a file within a controller and store some data in an object, but I cant manage to save it properly. Can anyone help? I am new in Groovy/Grails...

```
File generals = new File("C:/Grails/Grails-3.3.0/ggts/Test/data.txt")
def line = generals.readLines()
def date = new SetDate(params)
date.save()

date.title = ${line[0]}
date.location = ${line[1]}
date.description = ${line[2]}
date.name = ${line[3]}
date.email = ${line[4]} 
date.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may change `${line[0]}` to `"${line[0]}"` and all things alike if you want to use [string interpolation](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation).

And as line is a list of String, change `${line[0]}` to `line[0]` is also ok.

Comment: Yeah, the thing with data.readLines was a pure mistake, but the ".." thing made it happen! Thanks!

Comment: You don't need `"${line[0]}"` at all.  Just use `line[0]`.